# How to customize the headline in Beamer like this?

Tags: beamer

I don't know how to modify the headline in Beamer like this one, could someone help me with it?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code that generates the Beamer shown here and tell us what you want to do?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this headline with the `infolines` theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\begin{document}

    \section{Overview}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Part I}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I also want to add some words in the shaded bar besides "overview", is there any way I can make it?  And I also want the title of my slides embedded in shade, I use \useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is my code.                                                                               \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{utopia} 
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\title[About Beamer] %optional
{About the Beamer class in presentation making}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}